# TypeError('list indices must be integers, not str',)

Tags: python, sqlite, bottle

I wrote this piece of code where I am trying to add a new row to a table (database sqlite)

```
@get('/inventory/add')
def inventory_add(db):
    db.execute("INSERT INTO inventory (name, category, location, date, amount) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", (item['name'], item['category'], item['location'], item['date'],  item['amount']))

    db.commit()
```

At first when I executed it I got:

```
NameError("global name 'item' is not defined",)
```

so I digged around internet an in my inexperience with python I decided to declare item as a list in hope it would work:

```
item=[]
@get('/inventory/add')
def inventory_add(db):
    db.execute("INSERT INTO inventory (name, category, location, date, amount) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", (item['name'], item['category'],    item['location'], item['date'],  item['amount']))

    db.commit()
```

So after running the above code I got this:

```
TypeError('list indices must be integers, not str',)
```

Comment: Your `item` is a list. When you index it with `[]`, the index must be an integer number. `item['location']` is invalid, `item[0]` would be valid (but not necessarily correct). Alternatively, use dictionary: `item={}`. Then string indexes (actually, keys) are legal.

Comment: i tried `item={}` but when i run it i get : `KeyError: 'name' `

Comment: Show the code you used to initialize `item`.

Comment: Do not edit the question in a way that invalidates existing answers. If you have a new question, ask a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need here is a dictionary, not a list. So, try this:

```
item={'name':'somename', 'category':'somecat','location':'someloc', 'date':'somedate','amount':'someamt'}
```

(don't declare empty dictionary here, if the program doesn't know where to look in the dictionary it will obviously throw an error)
Then try your code, it should be working.

For the Cursor error, like DYZ said, you are trying to commit the cursor, but you should try to commit the instance with which you have made the connection to the database. Also please return something on your pages or the user will just get stuck when the page is accessed.

Comment: This is what i get after i did what you said:`AttributeError: 'sqlite3.Cursor' object has no attribute 'commit' `

Comment: @JDoe This is your _next_ problem, and it is separate from the list/dictionary problem. A cursor indded does not have a `.commit()` method. This method is a part of the database connection object.

Comment: @JDoe The error is for db.commit() my friend. Could you change the question to show the relevant code so i can access what might be the problem?

Comment: @JDoe Are you trying to do Web Technology at VU University Amsterdam Assignment 3? I couldnt help but google; you should try doing some more research for your assignment man there are lots of pages describing these errors and the official documentation of bottle also has many helpful examples to help with your assignment

Comment: I am going through the documentation of bottle right now hopefully will find something

Comment: @JDoe if my answer helped you solve the problem do you mind marking it as the answer? Thank you